# Check an event is processed or not after QCoreApplication::postEvent

Tags: qt, event-handling

I make user-event and send it an object in another thread using postEvent(). Since the receiver can be destroyed before it process the event, I want to know the event is processed or not. But QML doc says

> It is not safe to access the event after it has been posted.

Is there a way to know the event is processed or not?